# Mounting micro USB B connector on a PCB

Tags: pcb, usb, connector

[image: Micro USB B connector recommended PCB layout]

What's the best way to mount this on a PCB so that it is more reliable? Should I go with the flat tabs an no holes like they show and just solder the tabs to the dedicated pads or bend the tabs and put them into holes and solder that way?

Comment: If you're considering bending the tabs, why not use one with through-hole tabs in the first place?

Comment: This is the worst connector ever. Even if a bent tab variant is used, the entire mount has a pivotal point, and the connector shroud will bend/rock, and eventually the signal pads will break.

Answer (score 4):

Mount it as recommended. It will withstand the force needed to connect/disconnect. If you have space and will solder it by hand, you could increase the size of the front pads and drill some VIAs into it. This will prevent the pad from coming of and enforce the construction.

Comment: VIAs tying the copper to the substrate better because of the copper inside the VIAs bonding to the copper on the surface of the PCB and holding it down better?

Comment: Yes exactly. Also the solder flowing into the VIA gives extra strength.

Comment: The only way to salvage this part is to extend soldering pads (vertically) up to the entire length of the connector.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the mechanically weakest link is the pads trying to hold on to the PCB.

You could improve the strength of the pads by adding plated vias to them to pads on the other side of the PCB or to an inner layer. And solder that through of course.

But is a through-hole connector is acceptable then I would choose that.

Answer (score 3):

As shown, this is the least reliable mount, especially with regard to bending. This one is the worst. Connectors with two through holes are somewhat better. The usual problem is with signal pads. They break due to fatigue, and the fatigue is due to the shroud has excessive flexibility, due to very short solder footprint.

A connector with a bigger through-hole footprint ([solder tabs on all four corners](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/amphenol-fci/10103592-0001LF/609-4048-1-ND/2350355)) is way better.

However, for the real product (like a test fixture), people are using aluminum machined brackets on both sides, screwed together.

Obviously you should not use any ROHS solder, and should use the usual 60/40 (more malleable, mil-spec approved) solder if you want the connector to last up to its contact rating limit.

Answer (score 2):

Surface mount connectors are not made to withstand much more than normal insertion forces. What's really holding the connector on is how well the copper is bonded to the fiber substrate.

Normally, an surface mount connector will withstand normal insertion forces for the life of the product.

If you expect this connector to see more than normal insertion forces, then a connector with mechanical mounting tabs (through hole) will be a better bet.

Answer (score 2):

**Never ever** use SMD parts that will be subject to mechanical stress. Connectors like these should always be securely mounted and not rely on some pad on the pcb (which is generally very weak).

Answer (score 1):

If this will be seeing substantial strain, a connector with through hole mounting tabs is one way to go -- but encasing the board in a way so as to maximize mechanical stability is probably the more reliable approach.  How many cell phones have you seen where this connector breaks off the board?

Comment: I have seen quite a few hubs with broken/cracked data connections, especially of USB 3.0 type, where the matching cable is quite thick and sturdy.

Comment: @AliChen  -- then those hubs are not doing it well enough.  It doesn't invalidate the approach, just the instantiation.

Comment: I haven't read you answer to the end, sorry. Yes, I totally agree that mechanical encapsulation is a good way to ensure the connector reliability. The hubs I mention did not have any reinforcement.